# How do I perform a (nullable) one to zero or one relationship in Entity Framework, in combination with an entityID property?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I feel silly asking this, but, I just can't work out how to create a one to zero or one relationship, giving both an `entityID` and `entity` property.

Take the following example:

```
public class base
{
public int ID {get;set;}
}

public class linked
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string test {get;set;}
}
```

If I put `public virtual linked linked {get;set;}` into the base class, everything works as expected, I get a nullable 1 to 0 or 1 relationship.

However, I understand the benefits of using just an int/EntityID to store the relationship in combination with a virtual for lazy loading (e.g. `public int linkedID {get;set;}` in combination with the virtual above), but, I can't seem to work out how to create this, using the same relationship.

I have tried using the fluent API `Entity<base>().HasOptional(x=>x.linked).WithRequired()`, which is what I thought it should be, and this creates the 0 to 0 or 1 relationship, but, it is not nullable, which I do not understand given the `HasOptional`.

I thought I had turned a corner in understanding the Entity Framework, but this has really thrown me back! I can not understand where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
public int? linkedID {get;set;}
```

The int you where using isn't nullable so it would default to 0.

Comment: OMFG, I can not believe how simple it was! As you have to manually define items in the FluentAPI, I really wish there was some sort of Exception/error when it contradicts the model... Anyway.... I feel like an idiot over a simple `?` symbol! Thanks so much.